# Save didSelectRowAt on Tableview

Tags: swift

I want to record the didselectrowat I last closed. I want to save the didselectrowat I chose with userdefaults. When I try to assign data to indexpath, I get the error "Cannot assign to value: 'indexPath' is a 'let' constant'. How do I memorize indexpath?

```
 var savedata: IndexPath?

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
   // tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    print("deselectRow", indexPath)
    let save11 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "deselectRow")
    savedata = IndexPath(row: save11, section: 0)


    tableView.selectRow(at: savedata, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)


    if indexPath == [3,0] {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(60, forKey: "seconds")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(0, forKey: "deselectRow")

        }
     if indexPath == [3,1] {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(900, forKey: "seconds")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "deselectRow")

    }
```

Comment: To modify indexPath, you should make var indexPath = indexPath, because indexPath is parameter of cellForRow method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's useless to change the `indexPath` parameter because it has no effect at all.

To select another row you have to call `selectRow(at:animated:scrollPosition:)`.

Calling super in `didSelectRowAt` is not mandatory

```
var savedata: IndexPath?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let save11 = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "deselectRow")
    savedata = IndexPath(row: save11, section: 0)

    tableView.selectRow(at: savedata, animated: true, scrollPosition: .middle)

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(60, forKey: "deselectRow")
    }
```

Comment: I updated the code on the subject. I have to say, but it doesn't. When I quit the application, it does not choose the most recent indexpath I chose.

Comment: In this case you have to put the code to read from `UserDefaults` and to select the row in `viewWillAppear`, too.

Answer (score 0):

In swift, `let` is a constant. Using `var` will make it a variable and allow you to modify it